I have photo cards from the pictures that have been developed. I don't have the film rolls anymore.Is it possible to get photos out of the photocards?
I've lost the film rolls and I only have the photocards which shows you all the pictures that have been developed.
I got told to use the Epson perfection v600 which didn't help either.
I want to take those pictures out of the photo cards if it's possible?
Kind regards

So you have photos on paper, right? And what is the problem with v600, this is instrument exactly for this kind of work?

My reading of this question is that the OP only has a single "contact print", showing thumbnails of all the frames from the entire roll.

If you refer to a "contact sheet" meaning a printed strip of all the photos

No. You can not.
You can only extract a super low-resolution smudge of blurry things from that.
Sorry.

Worse! This is probably a thumbnail print onto 4x6in from a Frontier or Noritsu digital lab machine.  So not even an optical contact print (which you might be able to enlarge to bad 4x6's).

@davolfman Do those machines retain digital copies for any length of time?
